# How to rename the video recorded by MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on a simple app that records video for later process. How to store the recorded videos using predefined name? I'm working with API 29 or above, so the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not longer valid, what the current solution for this task.

I've tried to use `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`, but couldn't figure out the path part. Here's code I wrote.

```
 val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
 intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 5)
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, recordPath)  # how to set the path. 
 startActivityForResult(intent, 222)
```

To clarify, I would like to save files using predefined pattern, not the automatically generated name by `MediaStore`.

Comment: Unclear if you wanna rename afterwards or determine the file name at forehand.

Comment: I would like to rename afterwards. I've also made a update to the question.

Comment: "but couldn't figure out the path part" -- set up `FileProvider` and use its `getUriForFile()` to get a `Uri` pointing to some file that you control (e.g., in `getFilesDir()`). Use that `Uri` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. You use the same technique with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and it is more widely used, so you might search for some examples for it (e.g., [this older one of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Camera/FileProvider)).